# How to start map navigation in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I would like to start the navigation without any click on the screen.

I tried these two versions, but no one can start navigation without click (at least two clicks).

How to start navigation automatically?

```
let latitude:CLLocationDegrees = xx.xxxxx
let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = xx.xxxxx
```

Version 1:

```
let regiondistance:CLLocationDistance = 10000
let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
let regionspan  = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regiondistance, regiondistance)
let options = [MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey:NSValue(mkCoordinate:regionspan.center),MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey:NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan:regionspan.span)]

let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
let mapitem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
mapitem.name = "Name"
mapitem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)
```

Version 2:

```
let url = URL(string: String(format:"http://maps.apple.com/?ll=%f,%f", app.lat+0.002,app.lng+0.002))!
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 2 can be done with 1 click if you update your URL to:
http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=%f,%f&dirflg=d
Before clicking the GO button, users should be able to select the route they prefer.